# How to change textbox border styles in AppMaker

Tags: css, google-app-maker

I am trying to change the border styles for [inputfields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OchmD.png) that have the focus from the material design's blue border-color to green border-color, but the following CSS seems not be working:

```
.app-TextArea.focus .app-TextArea-Input, .app-TextBox.focus .app-TextBox-Input {
  border-bottom-color: green;
}
```

Maybe someone can help me out.

Comment: Just for clarification: I am referring to lower blue border that appears when a text-area or a textbox has the focus. I would like to change the color from blue to green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [CSS variant](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/styles#custom_variants) should make a trick

```css
.focus.app-TextBox--Green::after {
  border-bottom-color: green;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your answer works perfectly. I want to keep the CSS variant I am already using. So I changed it a little bit:

.app-TextBox.focus:after